# Как добавить скрипт при скролле?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, прокрутка, animate

Есть блок с диаграммой внутри которой находится число. Нашел скрипт "animateNumber.js" который анимирует это число от 0 до числа которое мне нужно. Но скрипт срабатывает сразу. Как сделать чтобы он срабатывал только когда я доскроллил до этого блока?

Вот скрипт:

```
$('.lines-1')
        .prop('number', 10)
        .animateNumber({ 
            number: 90 
        },
        3700
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю примерного код будет достаточно:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(e){
      var coord = $(".showMenu").offset();                
      if ( ($(window).height()+$(window).scrollTop() >= coord.top) && ($(window).scrollTop() - (coord.top + 25) < 0) ){
        $('#i_menu').css('display', 'block');
      } else {
        $('#i_menu').css('display', 'none')
      }
    })
})
```

```css
.showMenu{
    margin-top:800px;
    margin-bottom: 800px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#i_menu{
    display:none;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Крути вниз, пацанчик! <br />
<div class="showMenu">Отслеживаемый блок</div>
<div id="i_menu">Я - результат совершаемого действа!!!</div>
```

Здесь мы отслеживаем скролл. И если высота экрана + смещение скролла будет больше, чем значение высоты, на котором располагается отслеживаемый блок (margin-top:800px;) или наоборот, блок слишком высоко уезжает вверх, то делаем что-то. В данном случае просто показываем другой блок. В вашем случае это будет запуск таймера.