# Как показать модальное окно при прокрутке страницы с задержкой и в определенном блоке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Как показать модальное окно при прокрутке страницы именно в определенном блоке и с задержкой? Т.е. при прокрутке страницы, как только блок попадает в видимую часть экрана, появляется окно, и с задержкой, скажем, в 5 сек. Спасибо большое за помощь!

```js
$(function() {
  // закрываем окно
  $('.message').click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).add('.okay').click(function() {
    $('.click').show(); // показываем кнопку
    $('.message').removeClass('active');
  });
  // открываем окно
  $('.click').click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $(this).hide(); //скрываем кнопку
    $('.message').addClass('active');
  }).click();
});
```

```css
.click {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #260016;
}
.message {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 140px);
  left: calc(50% - 300px);
  width: 600px;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #fff;
  color: button;
  padding: 60px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.message.active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.okay {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #e68a6c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="map">
  <button class="click">Открыть</button>
  <div class="message">Сообщение
    <button class="okay">Закрыть</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаешь удалив вопрос и создав такой же на него скорее ответят?

Comment: Да ошибаешься, не так много вопросов задаются по данным меткам, кроме того отсутствие ответа ни о чем не говорит. Оно может быть по различным причинам. начиная от плохой формулировки, заканчивая отсутствием в данный момент людей хотевших ответить. Кроме того есть отдельный фильтр неотвеченных по метке. 6 часов не такой уж большой срок, чтобы думать, что ответ никто не увидит. В то же время удаление вопроса, может помешать отвечающему уже набравшему ответ, но не успевшему отправить, набирать его заново рискуя опять не успеть уже не будет никакого желания.

Comment: Что именно в вашем вопросе вы не можете сделать? Никто не хочет за вас писать готовый код. Логику работы вы сами же всю описали — "при прокрутке страницы с задержкой и в определенном блоке". Ещё раз — что не получается?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540755/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5/540760#540760 вот это не поможет? вроде что-то подобное ..прокрутка, появление блока и прочее.................. и как говорил @Grundy - не стоит удалять вопрос и заново задавать - за такое лично я минусую а еще банить хорошо)

Comment: @LADYX `25` - это высота `i_menu` там в `css` написано `height:25px;` .... можно конечно прямо измерять высоту нужного элемента и добавлять... там просто для наглядности было быстрое магическое число................выглядит да - как спамерство. Если никто не ответил - значит не нашлось людей кто мог бы помочь. Не все вопросы находят ответы. ruSO - не лекарство от всех болезней....И ведь не только у вас есть вопросы. А так получается как будто у вас только траблы, а на всех плевать. Да и все же - это база знаний, а не сайт фрилансеров. для быстрого решения проблем можно обращаться именно туда)

Comment: @LADYX про высоту я же написал: `можно конечно прямо измерять высоту нужного элемента и добавлять.` ..... то есть что-то типа `document.getElementById('mySuperItem').clientHeight`  или на `jquery` что-то аналогичное